# A tool that can decompose ternary expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

It seems the previous developers of the current project I'm working with decided to create some working yet unmanageable code.

Throughout the code I'm finding multi-conditional ternary expressions. It's getting to be a headache to translate and re-write/refactor them.

Does anyone know of a free tool, standalone or as an add-in for VS 2008, that can decompose ternary expressions? There's no budget for CodeRush on this project. I'll continue re-coding if needed, but I'm trying to have a little hope here.

Here's an example of the issue:

```
sNoteType = objSelection.Items[1].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[0].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[3].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " :
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " :
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ?
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "BA " : 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LS " : 
    objSelection.Items[3].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "BA " : 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "FD " : 
    objSelection.Items[0].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[3].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "BA " : 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LS " : 
    objSelection.Items[3].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "BA " : 
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "LT " : 
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty + "EV " : 
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 
    string.Empty + "OV " : 
    string.Empty;
```

Comment: Ouch. That's all I've got. Sorry.

Comment: You may want to post this on The Daily WTF.

Comment: Both CodeRush and ReSharper have free trials of its products that should be long enough for you to clean up this code. You can also justify purchasing a license to your management based on your productivity in cleaning up the code base.

Comment: +1 just because that code sample is HILARIOUS.  I feel your pain.  I'd try to figure out what it's actually trying to, because clearly 70+% of that code doesn't need to exist.  For starters, all of the string.Empties there are pointless.  Find/replace them all with nothing.  Do you have any requirement docs that has the requirement for this in English?  If not, try to start building a truth table with the cases to look for the pattern.  I can't be sure yet, but my guess an XOR of each of the selected items could be very useful.

Comment: A question tou should ask is this: _why_ are you mass-changing "workable yet unmanagable" code in the first place. If it's working, leave it alone - it's only unmanagable when you have to manage it, i.e., when you need to change one of those monstrosities due to an added or removed value (for example). _That's_ when you should refactor (and probably just that one).

Comment: @paxdiablo I imagine part of it is understanding the code.  It's important when supporting an app to have some idea of what it's doing; if you can't read the code, you don't know.  If you refactor it to something more readable, then you can support it better.

Comment: Whoever did that should be barred from ever programming again.

Comment: @Mark - Yes, it's quite painful.

Comment: @tawman - Sadly the budget isn't going to come.  If David's suggestion of CodeRush Xpress has no licensing issues, it's my best 
bet.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I'm tasked with getting it into a manageable state before bringing a new team on board.

Comment: wow.....
in editor of your choice

ctrl-a, delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeRush Xpress (free) does this and much more.  See [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/conditionals.xml).

Comment: In my haze of frustration I didn't even see the Xpress version on their site.  Thank you for pointing me here.

Answer (score 11):

The meaning of the code is really much simpler than it seems. Continuing with ReSharper found me the following:

```
string sNoteType;
var items = objSelection.Items;

var item0Selected = items[0].Selected;
string item3NotSelectedValue;
if (items[1].Selected)
{
    item3NotSelectedValue = item0Selected ? "LS " : "FD ";
}
else
{
    item3NotSelectedValue = item0Selected ? "LS " : string.Empty;
}

if (items[2].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "OV ";
}
else
{
    if (items[5].Selected)
    {
        sNoteType = "EV ";
    }
    else
    {
        if (items[4].Selected)
        {
            sNoteType = "LT ";
        }
        else
        {
            if (items[3].Selected)
            {
                sNoteType = "BA ";
            }
            else
            {
                sNoteType = item3NotSelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since Jon did all the hard work, here's an edit that *I think* boils it down to the essence. Obviously, you'd want to put tests around this code ASAP - as I can't imagine not making some mistake in decoding this monstrosity, and automated refactoring is only going to get you so far (not very, from the looks of the samples placed here):

```
var items = objSelection.Items;
string sNoteType = string.Empty;    
if (items[0].Selected && items[1].Selected) {
    sNoteType = "LS ";
} else if (items[1].Selected) {
    sNoteType = "FD ";
} else if (items[2].Selected) {
    sNoteType = "OV ";
} else if (items[3].Selected) {
    sNoteType = "BA ";    
} else if (items[4].Selected) {
    sNoteType = "LT ";
} else if (items[5].Selected) {
    sNoteType = "EV ";
}
```

Comment: Why Daniel Mann answer using ReSharper gives a much more complex output?

Comment: @Cœur he makes it one large if statement. I removed the duplication and found the structure is simpler.

Answer (score 8):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can convert ternary to if/else.

I actually ran it through ReSharper, and the output is equally terrifying. I wish you the best of luck in refactoring.

```
if (objSelection.Items[1].Selected)
            if (objSelection.Items[0].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LS ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "FD ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        else
        {
            if (objSelection.Items[0].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LS ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                        else
                        {
                            if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected) sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                            else sNoteType = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the research.  It's good know this community has support from users such as yourself.  I'm going to go with the CodeRush Xpress version so I don't get dependent a tool I won't be able to purchase later.

Comment: That code makes me weep.

Comment: Why John Saunders answer using ReSharper gives a much more simple output?

Answer (score 5):

This code should behave identically to the original monstrosity:

```
string sNoteType;
if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "OV ";
}
else if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "EV ";
}
else if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "LT ";
}
else if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "BA ";
}
else if (objSelection.Items[0].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "LS ";
}
else if (objSelection.Items[1].Selected)
{
    sNoteType = "FD ";
}
else
{
    sNoteType = string.Empty;
}
```

To arrive at this I started with the assumption that whatever the code is currently doing is correct. I then wrote a script to generate 64 test cases -- one for each combination of truth values. Imagine a bunch of this:

```
[TestCase("EV ", "000001")]
[TestCase("LT ", "000010")]
[TestCase("EV ", "000011")]
[TestCase("BA ", "000100")]
[TestCase("EV ", "000101")]
```

Then I eyeballed the patterns and added if-statements one by one until the monstrosity was no longer needed at all. I can't guarantee that this is how the original author was imagining the logic, but I *can* guarantee that it behaves identically in all possible cases.

Answer (score 3):

I converted it for you using my CodeRush Xpress

```
if (objSelection.Items[1].Selected)
    if (objSelection.Items[0].Selected)
        if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
        else
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LS ";
    else
        if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
        else
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "FD ";
else
    if (objSelection.Items[0].Selected)
        if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
        else
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LS ";
    else
        if (objSelection.Items[3].Selected)
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "BA ";
        else
            if (objSelection.Items[4].Selected)
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "LT ";
            else
                if (objSelection.Items[5].Selected)
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "EV ";
                else
                    if (objSelection.Items[2].Selected)
                        sNoteType = string.Empty + "OV ";
                    else
                        sNoteType = string.Empty;
```

However, this is still extremely ugly. I would suggest you to use a six dimensional truth table

```
string[,,,,,] table = new string[2,2,2,2,2,2];
table[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] = "AA";
table[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] = "BB";
table[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] = "CC";
table[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] = "DD";
...
```

It can then be queried like this

```
string sNoteType = table[
    objSelection.Items[0].Selected ? 1 : 0,
    objSelection.Items[1].Selected ? 1 : 0,
    objSelection.Items[2].Selected ? 1 : 0,
    objSelection.Items[3].Selected ? 1 : 0,
    objSelection.Items[4].Selected ? 1 : 0,
    objSelection.Items[5].Selected ? 1 : 0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to face such a situation, I'd use it to investigate Roslyn and see how it can help. I think developing a plugin for VS, refactoring the ternary expression you select, would fit a "weekend" project.

http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/23/exploring-how-to-write-a-code-analyzer-with-roslyn/ 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/11/03/using-the-roslyn-syntax-api.aspx

Comment: I like your approach of turning this mess into something fun!